# Doctrine2 select all "unseen" rows and / or up to 10 seen

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, union

I'm faced with the scenario where I have a table of notifications / messages. What I'm trying to do is to fetch:

- up to 10 messages
- all unread messages

with the restriction that if there is more than 10 unread messages, we only fetch these. So basically I want to end up having either 10 last messages (both unread and read) or n last unread messages if there's more than 10 of them.

Any idea? I can't provide you with any examples I've been trying, because I haven't even got to that point. Only solutions I came up with were based o UNION or SELECT FROM, both not supported by Doctrine unfortunately.

@EDIT

Just to make it clear, I want to fetch ALL unread messages and only fetch read messages if there's less than 10 unread messages to get MINIMUM of 10 messages displayed.

For a temporary solution I decided to use two queries. One to check count of unread messages and based on that I either fetch 10 messages (if count is less than 10) or all unread messages if count is more than 10. But I'd rather use a single query if possible and this is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

you can use **order by**. you only must change the compare in the **if**. i don't know how to compare the status of your messages

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        y.*
        , @nr := @nr +1 as nr
    FROM your_table y
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @nr:=0) as init
    ORDER BY if(`status` = 'unread', 1,2)
) as result
WHERE
    `status` = 'read'
OR
    (`status` = 'unread' and nr <= 10 );
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM your_table;
+----+--------+
| id | status |
+----+--------+
|  1 | unread |
|  2 | unread |
|  3 | unread |
|  4 | unread |
|  5 | unread |
|  6 | unread |
|  7 | read   |
|  8 | unread |
|  9 | read   |
| 10 | read   |
| 11 | read   |
| 12 | read   |
| 13 | unread |
| 14 | unread |
| 15 | unread |
| 16 | unread |
| 17 | unread |
| 18 | read   |
| 19 | read   |
+----+--------+
19 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> SELECT y.status , count(*)
    -> FROM your_table y
    -> GROUP BY y.status;
+--------+----------+
| status | count(*) |
+--------+----------+
| read   |        7 |
| unread |       12 |
+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**result**

```
mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT
    ->         y.*
    ->         , @nr := @nr +1 as nr
    ->     FROM your_table y
    ->     CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @nr:=0) as init
    ->     ORDER BY if(`status` = 'unread', 1,2)
    -> ) as result
    -> WHERE
    ->     `status` = 'read'
    -> OR
    ->     (`status` = 'unread' and nr <= 10 );
+----+--------+------+
| id | status | nr   |
+----+--------+------+
|  1 | unread |    1 |
|  2 | unread |    2 |
|  3 | unread |    3 |
|  4 | unread |    4 |
|  5 | unread |    5 |
|  6 | unread |    6 |
|  8 | unread |    7 |
| 13 | unread |    8 |
| 14 | unread |    9 |
| 15 | unread |   10 |
|  7 | read   |   13 |
|  9 | read   |   14 |
| 10 | read   |   15 |
| 11 | read   |   16 |
| 12 | read   |   17 |
| 18 | read   |   18 |
| 19 | read   |   19 |
+----+--------+------+
17 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: yeah, but this will limit to 10 in all circumstances and I need to fetch ALL unread messages if there are more than 10.

Comment: @user1970395 - sorry - i have change my answer

Comment: thanks a lot, you still have a tiny error there - `status` in `where` conditions should be the other way around ;) it's quite helpful, yes. Unfortunately this kind of query won't play well with `Doctrine2`, since I can't put subquery in `from` clause. I'll keep trying though!

Comment: @user1970395 - then you can put the subquery in a view and select them